# AWS Lambda S3 trigger error: Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have two AWS lambda functions that are the destinations of the same PREFIX/SUFFIX filter. The tuple (PREFIX,SUFFIX) looks like

```
myFolder/mySubfolder, .json
```

Both works and run without any issue.

Now I have created a new Lambda function, and I have tried to add it as destination for this new event notification, having the same tuple `myFolder/mySubfolder, .json` so a trigger on the same bucket folder's prefix and suffix.

But this time I get and error:

> An error occurred when creating the trigger: Configuration is ambiguously defined. Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: xxxxx; S3 Extended Request ID: xxxxxx; Proxy: null)

telling me that I cannot have an overlapping suffix (i.e. `.json`) in two (different) rules when the prefixes (i.e. `myFolder/mySubfolder`) are overlapping for the same type `All object create events`, so this means that according to the error the tuple to be considered would be

```
(event_type, eventy_prefix, event_suffix)
```

and this shall be unique. In fact, of the two previous triggers, one is for `All object create events` and another is for `All object create events`. So I cannot have a second on those type like:

```
('All object create events', myFolder/mySubfolder, .json)
```

That said, any alternative solution to avoid this limitation of the event notifications trigger?

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? I have a similar situation where i'm trying to send ".txt" suffix filtered S3 Notifications to a new SQS queue which currently being sent to a SNS Topic. AWS keeps on throwing "Configuration is ambiguously defined. Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type." Any suggestions.